# Memory leak with getline and strsep

Tags: c, memory-leaks

Get a memory leak while using `getline` together with `strsep`. I know `strsep` modifies `line` - could this be the cause? That `line` is not freed correctly.

```
  FILE *file = fopen("keywords.txt", "r");
  if (file) {
    char* line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1) {  // Line 35

      char *token;
      while ((token = strsep(&line, "\t")) != NULL) {
        // Do stuff
      }

    }

    free(line);
    fclose(file);
  }
```

Valgrind returns this:

```
==6094== 4,680 bytes in 39 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 7 of 7
==6094==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6094==    by 0x51AEBB4: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:66)
==6094==    by 0x4009B3: read_keywords (main.c:35)
==6094==    by 0x400959: renew_init (main.c:64)
==6094==    by 0x400A48: main (main.c:68)
```

If I comment out `strsep`, there's no memory leak.

Tips?

Comment: You are altering `token`. That is the pointer you should finally give to free. But you altered it beyond recognition.

Comment: Yeah, I removed `free(token)`, but same result from Valgrind.

Comment: You updated the question? That is very confusing. (and impolite, IMHO)

Comment: Be aware that getline does not update the value pointed to by its second argument with the length of the line read, but with the size of the buffer allocated or reallocated with malloc.  The line length is the return value.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you pass `&line` to `strsep`, it will change the value of `line`. At the end of the inner loop, `line` will be `NULL` and `free(line)` will do nothing. This will also cause `getline` to allocate a new buffer instead of reusing the current one.

You should copy `line` to a new variable, e.g. `char *line2 = line;` and pass `&line2` to `strsep`.