# memory leak when reading file line by line using getline

Tags: c, file-io, memory-leaks

I am using getline to read a file line by line. Valgrind is telling me I am getting a memory leak, and I'm not sure what malloc'ed memory I'm not freeing.

EDIT: In response to the comments I'd like to clarify: I cannot free the "token" variable without getting an error message from valgrind, but I can free the "line" variable, which I now do after the loop (see the code below). Despite the fact I have the "free(line)" at the end of the loop, I am still getting a memory leak message from valgrind. Adding a "free(line)" inside the loop does not fix this problem.

I am essentially reading lines of text from a file, then assigning the relevant information from that line to a struct. The relevant code is:

```c
    struct initial_data_params s_ID = {} ;

    char* line  = NULL ;
    char* token = NULL ;
    size_t len = 0 ; 
    ssize_t read = 0 ; 

    FILE* pf_initial_data = fopen(fN_initial_data, "r") ;

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, pf_initial_data)) != -1) {
        token = strsep(&line, "=") ;
        if ((token != NULL) &&  (strcmp(token, "r2Exp_amp") ==0)) {
            token = strsep(&line, "=") ;
            if (token != NULL) {
                s_ID.r2Exp_amp = strtod(token, NULL) ;
            }
        }
        (do something like this 9 more times for 9 other paramters)
}
fclose(pf_initial_data) ;
free(line) ;
line = NULL ;
return s_ID ;
```

Valgrind is telling me I have a memory leak at

```c
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, pf_initial_data)) != -1)
```

in particular it says at that line that

```c
==172360== 1,200 bytes in 10 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 57 of 58
==172360==    at 0x4C29BC3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==172360==    by 0x5CE0744: getdelim (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==172360==    by 0x416321: read_initial_data (file_io.c:38)
==172360==    by 0x402FA4: main (main.c:14)
```

I should add: if you think there is a *better* way to read a file line by line and pick out a specific string/character array from that line in c than using getline, I'd be happy to see that as well.

Comment: You should check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686220/memory-leak-with-getline-and-strsep

Comment: How exactly did you try to `free` the memory and what error do you get? Does the number of lost blocks correspond to the loop cycles? According to `man getline` it should allocate the buffer on the first call (`line = NULL`) and `realloc` if necessary on subsequent calls, so the number of leaked blocks should correspond to how many times you run the code snippet from your question.

Comment: @Bodo I tried "free(line); free(token)" and I get a "Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()" in valgrind for the line I "free(token)"

Comment: `free(token)` is wrong because `token` points to somewhere in the memory pointed to by `line`, see `man strsep`. `free(line);line=NULL;` would be correct. Without `line=NULL;` a subsequent `getline` would try to re-use the memory you just `free`d. Please [edit] your question and add the information from your comment.

Comment: See Philippe's comment, especially the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28686287/10622916. You should not pass `&line` to `strsep` because it will modify `line`. Maybe use `char *line2 = line; ...strsep(&line2`, ...)`

Comment: @Bodo I think you're right.  It sure looks like a dupe to me.  I'll wait a bit before voting to close.  Others may not wait, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must free the memory returned by getline.  From man(3) getline:

> If *lineptr is set to NULL and *n is set 0 before the call, then
>   getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This buffer
>   should be freed by the user program even if getline() failed.

Comment: I now have a "free(line);" at the end of each iteration of the loop, and a "free(line) ; line=NULL;" after the loop, but valgrind is still registering a memory leak-now it's just one less block that is not leaked.

Comment: It should not be necessary to `free` the memory in every loop cycle because `getline` re-uses an existing buffer and uses `realloc` if necessary. It should be sufficient to `free` the memory once after the loop.

Comment: See Philippe's comment to the question, especially the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28686287/10622916

Comment: This is wrong on multiple levels. *line should be free'd (or copied for later freeing) and set to NULL when you're done with it* combined with *It must also be free'd after the loop* would result in a double free.  Also, [`getline()` uses `realloc()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html): "an object shall be allocated as if by `malloc()` or the object shall be reallocated as if by `realloc()`"

Comment: Ah missed the point about realloc in the man page.  I don't see how it would result in a double free though if freeing/NULLing in each iteration?

Answer (score 2):

According to this link: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html
if there are no enough memory for the new line in the given buffer, the function **getline** will allocate a new memory for the new line using realloc.

In your case, you have initialized your **char* line** to NULL, which means the **getline** function will not find a space for the new line, and will allocate a new memory for it. So, you need to free the line after you stopped using it.

```
fclose(pf_initial_data);
free(line);    //simply add this line
return s_ID;
```