# Valgrind shows 7 allocs and 7 frees, but still shows memory leaking?

Tags: c, memory-leaks

Can someone please explain to me why my program has memory leaks when I have 7 allocs and 7 frees? Below is my c code and its Valgrind output message.

Main function

```
int main() {

        char* path = "input_files/bdds/var25.bdd";
        int num_vars = get_num_vars(path);
        int num_nodes = get_num_nodes(path);

        printf("Num vars = %d\nNum nodes = %d\n", num_vars, num_nodes);

        return 0;

}
```

Both of my functions that have memory leaks behave very similar.

First function that's leaking memory

```
int get_num_vars(char* path) {
        FILE* fptr;
        size_t length = 0;
        char* buffer;
        char num_vars_str[3]; // Max num vars being read is double digits

        fptr = fopen(path, "r");
        if(fptr == NULL) {
                printf("Error opening file.\n");
        }

        // Copying input from first line, starting at the 5th element
        getline(&buffer, &length, fptr);
        buffer+=5;

        int counter = 0;
        while(*buffer != '\n') {
                num_vars_str[counter++] = *buffer++;
        }
        num_vars_str[counter] = '\0';
        fclose(fptr);
        free(buffer);
        return atoi(num_vars_str);
}
```

Second Function that's leaking memory

```
int get_num_nodes(char* path) {
        FILE* fptr;
        size_t length = 0;
        char* buffer;
        char num_nodes_str[4]; // Max num nodes being read is triple digits

        fptr = fopen(path, "r");
        if(fptr == NULL) {
                printf("Error opening file.\n");
        }

        // Copying input from second line, starting at the 6th element
        getline(&buffer, &length, fptr);
        getline(&buffer, &length, fptr);
        buffer+=6;

        int counter = 0;
        while(*buffer != '\n') {
                num_nodes_str[counter++] = *buffer++;
        }
        num_nodes_str[counter] = '\0';
        fclose(fptr);
        free(buffer);
        return atoi(num_nodes_str);
}
```

Valgrind output message

```
==423== HEAP SUMMARY:
==423==     in use at exit: 240 bytes in 2 blocks
==423==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 7 frees, 2,720 bytes allocated
==423==
==423== 120 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==423==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==423==    by 0x48E06C3: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:62)
==423==    by 0x109535: get_num_vars (in /home/koreylombardi17/vlsi/flow-computing/flowComputing)
==423==    by 0x10926B: main (in /home/koreylombardi17/vlsi/flow-computing/flowComputing)
==423==
==423== 120 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==423==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==423==    by 0x48E06C3: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:62)
==423==    by 0x109620: get_num_nodes (in /home/koreylombardi17/vlsi/flow-computing/flowComputing)
==423==    by 0x10927A: main (in /home/koreylombardi17/vlsi/flow-computing/flowComputing)
==423==
==423== LEAK SUMMARY:
==423==    definitely lost: 240 bytes in 2 blocks
==423==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==423==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==423==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==423==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Comment: Suggest `char* buffer;` --> `char* buffer = 0;`

Comment: Firstly, you are not calling `getline` correctly.  The first arg needs to be a pointer to a valid buffer or NULL. You don't init `buffer` at all so possibly passing garbage to `getline`. The second error is that you change the `buffer` pointer, e.g. here `buffer+=5;`. Which means the `free(buffer)` is invoking undefined behaviour as the pointer is not the same as the one returned by `malloc,`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55731141/memory-leak-when-reading-file-line-by-line-using-getline) (and linked duplicate) may help - there are conditions where `getline` can leak memory if not used correctly.